# How to show background image on CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, linphone, callkit

I want to show the background image on Call kit when a call is coming.I have searched a lot but not find any solution.And also I want to open the app when the phone is locked.Please help me
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think it's not possible.

Comment: So what's another option to do this?

Comment: No maybe! It's coming from the system side

Comment: you can only detect phone lock and unlock event when your app is running in background otherwise you can't handle call events.

Comment: you can only detect phone lock and unlock event when your app is running in background otherwise you can't handle call events.

Comment: so is it possible to open the app when call received in phone lock state?

Answer (score 0):

If your app has requested and been granted access to the user's Contacts database, it can modify the Contacts database to add a photo to any entry. So although there is no API to directly supply an image to be shown for a CallKit call, you may be able to modify or create a Contact database entry for a given caller before notifying the system of the incoming call via the `-reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:update:reply:` API, and then that Contact entry's photo will be shown.

Comment: So when the call is ended can I delete the created contact from Contacts database.